# ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 16])

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to reproduce the multi-input neural network of this tutorial: [tutorial](https://rosenfelder.ai/multi-input-neural-network-pytorch/#multi-input-deep-neural-network). This article uses PyTorch Lightning, while I want to use PyTorch, so I am adapting to my case. Basically I created my dataloaders and my network:

```
# Define loaders
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=64, num_workers=2, drop_last=True, shuffle=True)
val_loader   = DataLoader(val_set,   batch_size=64, num_workers=2, drop_last=False, shuffle=False)
test_loader  = DataLoader(test_set,  batch_size=64, num_workers=2, drop_last=False, shuffle=False)

def conv_block(input_size, output_size):
    block = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(input_size, output_size, (3, 3)), nn.BatchNorm2d(output_size), nn.ReLU(), nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2)),
    )

    return block

class SimpleCNN(nn.Module):

  #Constructor
  def __init__(self):
    # Call parent contructor
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = conv_block(3, 16)
    self.conv2 = conv_block(16, 32)
    self.conv3 = conv_block(32, 64)

    self.ln1 = nn.Linear(64 * 26 * 26, 16)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.batchnorm = nn.BatchNorm1d(16)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d(0.5)
    self.ln2 = nn.Linear(16, 5)

    self.ln4 = nn.Linear(5, 10)
    self.ln5 = nn.Linear(10, 10)
    self.ln6 = nn.Linear(10, 5)
    self.ln7 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
  # Forward
  def forward(self, img, tab):
    img = self.conv1(img)

    img = self.conv2(img)
    img = self.conv3(img)
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], -1)
    img = self.ln1(img)
    img = self.relu(img)
    img = self.batchnorm(img)
    img = self.dropout(img)
    img = self.ln2(img)
    img = self.relu(img)

    tab = self.ln4(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)
    tab = self.ln5(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)
    tab = self.ln6(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)

    x = torch.cat((img, tab), dim=1)
    x = self.relu(x)

    return self.ln7(x)
```

Now, I try to pass a sample to my network to check if it works correctly, in order to start training later:

```
# Create the model
model = SimpleCNN()
img_x, tab_x, label_x = train_set[0]
print(img_x.shape, tab_x, label_x)
img_x
img_x = img_x.unsqueeze(dim=0)
output = model(img_x, tab_x)
output.shape
```

But here, I have this error: `ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 16])` at this line:

```
----> 4 output = model(img_x, tab_x)
........
---> 37 img = self.batchnorm(img)
```

I know that probably is because I am passing only one element to my network (I am not sure). However, If I remove that line from my neural network, so basically changing the forward method in this way:

```
def forward(self, img, tab):
    img = self.conv1(img)

    img = self.conv2(img)
    img = self.conv3(img)
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], -1)
    img = self.ln1(img)
    img = self.relu(img)
    img = self.dropout(img)
    img = self.ln2(img)
    img = self.relu(img)

    tab = self.ln4(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)
    tab = self.ln5(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)
    tab = self.ln6(tab)
    tab = self.relu(tab)

    x = torch.cat((img, tab), dim=1)
    x = self.relu(x)

    return self.ln7(x)
```

then I have this other error: `RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1` but this time referred to this line: `---> 49 x = torch.cat((img, tab), dim=1)`

Edit: I solved the second error `RuntimeError: Tensors must have same number of dimensions: got 2 and 1`: basically I needed to unsqueeze also the tab_x in input:

```
model = SimpleCNN()
img_x, tab_x, label_x = train_set[0]
img_x = img_x.unsqueeze(dim=0)
tab_x = tab_x.unsqueeze(dim=0)
output = model(img_x, tab_x)
output.shape
```

and my output shape is `torch.Size([1, 1])`. However, I am still not able to fix the first error (the one in title)

Edit for @Edwin: I am printing the shapes in this way:

```
def forward(self, img, tab):
    img = self.conv1(img)
    print(img.shape)
    img = self.conv2(img)
    print(img.shape)
    img = self.conv3(img)
    print(img.shape)
    img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], -1)
    print(img.shape)
    img = self.ln1(img)
    print(img.shape)

    ...
    output:

    torch.Size([1, 16, 111, 111])
    torch.Size([1, 32, 54, 54])
    torch.Size([1, 64, 26, 26])
    torch.Size([1, 43264])
    torch.Size([1, 16])
```

Comment: a hint you can try printing out the shape of your inputs

Comment: @EdwinCheong I added the changes in the original post